# getListItems from SharePoint List dosen't work

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, caml, spservices

I have a Website-Collection with this url:

https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/

(Lists are located here:)

https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/Lists/

and a script wich I want to put into a ContentWebEditor-WebPart on the default.aspx in this WebSite-Collection:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.effect.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.js"></script>

<ul id="tasksUL">
   <li>First Item</li>
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 $().SPServices({
         operation: "GetListItems",
         webURL: "Lists/",
         listName: "Announcements",
         async: true,
         completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
     console.log($(xData.responseXML));
 $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
  var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
  $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
 });
         }
     });
});
</script>
```

My problem is, that I don't get any Items from this List. First I thought, that my webURL isn't correct. But I think its ok.

This is what the FireFox-Console is telling me regarding this topic:

> [10:50:36.567] GET https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/default.aspx
>   [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 996ms]  [10:50:37.274] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/1033/styles/core.css?rev=5msmprmeONfN6lJ3wtbAlA%3D%3D
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 186ms]  [10:50:37.275] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/1033/init.js?rev=SKi7C%2FTrsh1U%2FCnIwkB9Ag%3D%3D
>   [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 296ms]  [10:50:37.276] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/portal.js?rev=cRI8b5r5N%2BkLhIuWR03ICg%3D%3D
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 287ms]  [10:50:37.278] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/1033/non_ie.js?rev=yfNry4hY0Gwa%2FPDNGrqXVg%3D%3D
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 250ms]  [10:50:37.280] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/WebResource.axd?d=xIUuOuE98ByfhEVw86s2-wsvSC23O-MG2j2RCiSYrBW3eENvird3FGtTl7n5Ey8MA6YczOwHqe-nF_MjkubOu-Fs9YM1&t=634208849469717278
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 437ms]  [10:50:37.281] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/WebResource.axd?d=coyRyDekjahDPLQl45NQFykt1JFYYy3biV8NJQ0qsgkE-xbjFHLfY0XzXI4lou9RbTZ-LhJvLTejwoR3UsTN9S3AWkk1&t=634208849469717278
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 438ms]  [10:50:37.478] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/js/jquery-1.9.1.js [HTTP/1.1 304
>   Not Modified 222ms]  [10:50:37.480] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/js/jquery.ui.core.js [HTTP/1.1
>   304 Not Modified 232ms]  [10:50:37.481] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/js/jquery.ui.effect.js [HTTP/1.1
>   304 Not Modified 230ms]  [10:50:37.482] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/js/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.js
>   [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 240ms]  [10:50:37.593] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/1033/init.js?rev=SKi7C%2FTrsh1U%2FCnIwkB9Ag%3D%3D
>   [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 324ms]  [10:50:37.597] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/1033/core.js?rev=mHKsOQ0iU3Q5jdm9OZNDdg%3D%3D
>   [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 799ms]  [10:50:37.599] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/1033/search.js?rev=yqBjpvg%2Foi3KG5XVf%2FStmA%3D%3D
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 798ms]  [10:50:37.782] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/js/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.js
>   [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 617ms]  [10:50:37.919] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/1033/init.js?rev=SKi7C%2FTrsh1U%2FCnIwkB9Ag%3D%3D
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 475ms]  [10:50:38.493] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/js/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.js
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 655ms]  [10:50:38.494] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/1033/core.js?rev=mHKsOQ0iU3Q5jdm9OZNDdg%3D%3D
>   [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 649ms]  [10:50:38.495] GET
>   https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
>   533ms]  [10:50:38.495] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/blank.gif [HTTP/1.1 304
>   Not Modified 538ms]  [10:50:38.495] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/menudark.gif [HTTP/1.1 304
>   Not Modified 536ms]  [10:50:38.496] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/helpicon.gif [HTTP/1.1 304
>   Not Modified 536ms]  [10:50:38.496] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/FormServerTemplates/logo_altran.png
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 539ms]  [10:50:38.497] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/gosearch.gif [HTTP/1.1 304
>   Not Modified 830ms]  [10:50:38.497] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/whitearrow.gif [HTTP/1.1
>   304 Not Modified 870ms]  [10:50:38.498] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/recycbin.gif [HTTP/1.1 304
>   Not Modified 880ms]  [10:50:38.499] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/siteTitleBKGD.gif
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 881ms]  [10:50:38.499] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/topnavselected.gif
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 902ms]  [10:50:38.500] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/topnavunselected.gif
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1008ms]  [10:50:38.500] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/siteactionsmenugrad.gif
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1021ms]  [10:50:38.501] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/pageTitleBKGD.gif
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1021ms]  [10:50:38.501] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/topshape.jpg [HTTP/1.1 304
>   Not Modified 1039ms]  [10:50:38.502] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/navshape.jpg [HTTP/1.1 304
>   Not Modified 1039ms]  [10:50:38.502] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/quickLaunchHeader.gif
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1128ms]  [10:50:39.121] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/1033/core.js?rev=mHKsOQ0iU3Q5jdm9OZNDdg%3D%3D
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 345ms]  [10:50:39.167] GET
>   https://ssl.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.4.3&utms=4&utmn=1908043118&utmhn=directv2.altran.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1600x900&utmvp=1600x412&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=de-de&utmje=1&utmfl=11.7%20r700&utmdt=Home%20-%20BU%20Holger%20Bartels&utmhid=1021575290&utmr=-&utmp=%2Fcom%2Fbuhb%2Fdefault.aspx&utmht=1373446239026&utmac=UA-27185626-1&utmcc=__utma%3D124039967.1382262210.1373437685.1373437685.1373446038.2%3B%2B__utmz%3D124039967.1373437685.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=q~ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 285ms]  [10:50:39.168] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/Menu1.gif [HTTP/1.1 304
>   Not Modified 450ms]  [10:50:39.168] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/js/jquery-1.9.1.js [HTTP/1.1 304
>   Not Modified 311ms]  [10:50:39.169] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/icons/icons.png [HTTP/1.1 304 Not
>   Modified 500ms]  [10:50:39.591] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/js/jquery.ui.core.js [HTTP/1.1
>   304 Not Modified 144ms]  [10:50:39.736] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/js/jquery.ui.effect.js [HTTP/1.1
>   304 Not Modified 165ms]  [10:50:39.939] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/js/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.js
>   [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 562ms]  [10:50:40.686] GET
>   https://directv2.altran.com/_layouts/images/pagebackgrad.gif [HTTP/1.1
>   304 Not Modified 752ms]  [10:50:40.686] POST
>   https://directv2.altran.com/com/buhb/Lists/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
>   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 765ms]  [10:50:41.401] [object Object]

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think the "WebUrl" parameter should be "/com/buhb/" and not "Lists/"

Comment: unfirnately this also doesn't work

Comment: I looked up the error code for HTTP 304:

    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_304#3xx_Redirection

Which is:

    304 Not ModifiedIndicates that the resource has not been modified since the version specified by the request headers If-Modified-Since or If-Match.[2] This means that there is no need to retransmit the resource, since the client still has a previously-downloaded copy.

This may sound crazy, but do you think your NetScaler/Firewall/Network hardware is preventing the resources from being redownloaded because they are cached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried upgrading to SPServices version 2014.01? 2013.01 gave me a ton of issues and forced me to drop back to v0.7.2. Upgrading today to 2014.01 worked like a charm.

http://spservices.codeplex.com/releases/view/116626

Also - have you tried putting your fully qualified URL into the webURL field instead of just the relative URL?

Comment: sorry for the late answer ;)